# PodioForbiddenError in adding contact

Tags: php, api, podio

I am trying to add new contact item in my app: https://podio.com/myorg-3q695n94um/dealer-sales-a
Currently trying to adding a new contact Item in the app. But got this error again and again.
The app with id 8047729 does not have the right view on profile with id 123684408" Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/app/8047729/
Please help me to solve the issue.

```
$item_new_add[] = new PodioContactItemField('customer-name-2');

$item_new->fields = $item_new_add;

$item_new->field('customer-name-2')->set_value($contact_item_val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see examples for setting values for contact fields at: http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/#contact-field

Of course the entity you are authenticating as must have access to the contact you are adding. This typically results in errors when you are authenticating as an app and trying to add a contact that doesn't belong to any items in that app.